# Time Complexity for Python built-ins?

Tags: python-3.x, big-o

Is there any good reference resource to know the time complexity of Python's built-in functions like `dict.fromkeys()`, `.lower()`? I found links like this [UCI resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt%20which) which lists time-complexity for basic list & set operations but of course, not for all built-ins. I also found Python Reference - The Right Way but most of [references](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/fromkeys.html) have #TODO for time complexity.

I also tried reading the source code of python built-ins to figure out how the functions like `dict.fromkeys()` are implemented but felt lost.

Comment: One resource: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @AChampion: Thanks for providing the link but it also doesn't provide info on time complexity for string data types, and also misses operations (like `dict.fromkeys()`) while listing operations on dict.

Comment: did you find out time complexity of .lower() @Vimanyu

Answer (score 2):

This is a great place to start:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

It says that Get Item is O(1) and Iteration is O(n) (Average Case).
So then, if with `.fromkeys()` you iterate over just the keys of the dict, then make those the keys of a new dict, while also setting values, I'd think that you'd have between O(n) and O(2n), where n is the number of keys in the first dict.

Sorry that I can't offer more than conjecture, but hopefully that link is helpful.